# Samsung Galaxy S3 direct call always calls the same number

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, direct-call

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 and the direct call feature always calls the same number no matter whose contact I am viewing. Is this a bug in the feature? (The number it calls to is one of my frequent callers.)

Comment: Well, I rebooted the phone and it is working fine now, but still not sure why this happens. It happened to me twice and works fine when I reboot the phone. This is not an answer to my question but more like a solution to overcome that.

Comment: Could you nevertheless post this as answer and mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I rebooted the phone and it is working fine now, but still not sure why this happens. It happened to me twice and works fine when I reboot the phone. This is not an answer to my question but more like a solution to overcome that